# outside of scope when use a service in Configure method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Below is pseudo code from my textbook, and I'm confused about use a service in configure method

```
public class ConcreteA
{
   public static Run(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      ConcreteB _concrete = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConcreteB>();
      ... //use ConcreteB  instance
   }

}
__________________________________________________________

// startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
   services.AddScoped<ConcreteA>;
   services.AddScoped<ConcreteB>;  
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
   app.UseStatusCodePages();
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
   ConcreteA.Run(app.ApplicationServices);
}
```

I was told that becuase I use `ConcreteA` in `Configure` ,method, so I'm running this outside of a scope. Any dependency(ConcreteB instance in this case) I create will hang around.

I'm very confused, below is my questions:

Q1- I registered `ConcreteA` and `ConcreteB` both as `AddScoped`, so there shouldn't be any captured dependencies issues as they are in same scope, so why `ConcreteB` will still hang around.

Q2- I didn't even create a ConcreteA instance as the method I access is a static method, so **no** ConcreteA instance needs to be created. So it is even more impossible for `ConcreteB` to hang around.

Comment: In my opinion that is not the way you use dependency injection. You should let the DI engine handle the instantiation by having a constructor ConcreteA(ConcreteB instance).  I would not even use DI for instances handled inside the startup class.  DI is in my opinion is for other classes down the object graph.... That is the purpose of Inversion of Control through Dependency Injection... The caller should instantiate the dependencies... But in the case of the Startup class: Who is the caller? Is the caller the same as the consumer?  If the answer is Caller equals Consumer then DI is not needed.

Comment: @John  from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651750/disable-the-dependency-injection-scope-validation-feature-in-the-program-class/57652261?noredirect=1#comment101775460_57652261

Comment: @Darkonekt   The author of the textbook use this method to create an admin account in the beginning in regards to ASP.NET Core Identity. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651750/disable-the-dependency-injection-scope-validation-feature-in-the-program-class/57652261?noredirect=1#comment101775460_57652261

Comment: I get the logic, I think. DI containers will typically take care of disposing `IDisposable` objects that go out of scope, etc. but with your code you're not operating within a scope, so the container won't be able to manage these for you. For managed objects, garbage collection will still occur as normal, but for anything unmanaged that's owned (even indirectly) by `ConcreteB`, it won't automatically be disposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer in regards to your confusion explicitly: You have to think about the service provider as a cache of objects. When it creates a service that is not registered as transient, then it will store that instance locally so that it can provide the *same* instance again at a later time.

For example, when you do the following (assuming `IFoo` is not registered as transient), then it will resolve the same object instance:

```
serviceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
serviceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
```

In order to do that, the service provider has to remember the `IFoo` it returned in the very first call, so it can return the same instance on the second call (and any other call).

So what is a scope? A scope basically tells the service provider to resolve services from a *separate* cache. When you are within a scope and you now resolve a scoped service `IScopedBar`, then the instance the service provider creates for you will be cached in that scoped cache:

```
serviceProvider.GetService<IScopedBar>();
serviceProvider.GetService<IScopedBar>();
```

When you are within a scope and you resolve a singleton service, then that service will still be looked up in the main cache. But scoped services will be looked up in the scoped cache.

That all wouldn’t really make a difference if a scope wouldn’t be closed. When a scope is closed, which is done when it gets disposed (e.g. when the `using` block ends), then the services in the scoped cache are disposed and the cache is cleared. The main cache however stays.

If we were to implement that in a simplified pseudo service provider class, it could look like this:

```
public class SimplifiedServiceProvider
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> mainCache = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    private Dictionary<Type, object> scopeCache = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public object GetService(Type type)
    {
         var serviceLifetime = GetLifetimeForService(type);

         if (serviceLifetime == ServiceLifetime.Transient)
         {
             // transients are created directly
             return CreateNewInstance(type);
         }
         else if (serviceLifetime == ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
         {
             // try to get from the cache
             if (!mainCache.TryGetValue(type, out var service))
             {
                 // create the service first
                 service = CreateNewInstance(type);
                 mainCache.Add(type, service);
             }
             return service;
         }
         else if (serviceLifetime == ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
         {
             // try to get from the scope cache
             if (!scopeCache.TryGetValue(type, out var service))
             {
                 // create the service first
                 service = CreateNewInstance(type);
                 scopeCache.Add(type, service);
             }
             return service;
         }
    }

    public void DisposeScope()
    {
        // dispose all created (disposable) instances
        foreach (var instance in scopeCache.Values)
            (instance as IDisposable)?.Dispose();

        // reset cache
        scopeCache.Clear();
    }

    private ServiceLifetime GetLifetimeForService(Type type) { … }
    private object CreateNewInstance(Type type) { … }
}
```

(The real implementation of a service provider and service scopes is obviously a bit more complicated than this, but this should still give a good idea of how scoped dependencies differ from singletons.)

With that idea and pseudo implementation in mind, imagine what happens when you resolve a scoped service outside of a scope, so `DisposeScope` would never be called: The created scoped service would just stay permanently inside of the scope cache; just like singletons stay permanently within the main cache.

So by resolving a scoped service *outside of a service scope*, you effectively lifted the lifetime of that instance up to be a singleton service. This will not affect instances that actually *are* created within a scope, but those instances that are created outside of a scope will live for the lifetime of the service provider, which usually is the lifetime of the application.

That is why you usually want to create a temporary scope when you want to consume scoped services outside of “natural scopes” (i.e. scopes that are automatically created for you, like ASP.NET Core does when handling a request). That way, you restrict the lifetime of that scope, and as such also the lifetime of the instances that you resolve.

Comment: so you mean  my ConcreteB  instance `_concrete ` was created under the root scope of DI container?

Comment: Basically yes, because `Configure` doesn’t execute within a scope but rather at the very root.

Comment: and if I register `ConcreteA` and `ConcreteB ` as "transient" or "singleton", that won't be any out of scope problems, the out of scope problem only occurs when I register them as "scoped", am I correct?

Comment: If you register them differently, you are only avoiding the protection the DI scope validation gives you. Making the dependency an actual singleton will still prevent its dependencies from being released eventually. And if you make them transient, they won’t be disposed either until the service provider itself is eventually disposed. So only scoped dependencies have a properly managed lifetime. Creating a temporary scope is definitely the correct approach.

Comment: I think I understand the "transient" part. But if I register both of them as "Singleton", they will get disposed with ServiceProvider together, which is want we want,  that 's why  "Singleton" mean, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, they will be disposed when the service provider gets disposed, but that means that they will be around for the lifetime of the application. And that’s usually not what you want when e.g. the service contains a database connection. You don’t want to keep that open that long. You want to close it as soon as possible.

Comment: thank your very much, I got it. Your simplified pseudo service provider class helped a lot, you're a legend!

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I believe you are trying to achieve the following but first you would need to refactor `ConcreteA` to explicitly depend on `ConcreteB` via constructor injection *(though dependency on concretions as a code smell is outside of the scope (pardon the pun) of this question in its current form)*

```
public class ConcreteA {
    private ConcreteB B;

    public ConcreteA(ConcreteB B) {
        this.B = B;
    }

    public void Run() {
        ... //use ConcreteB  instance
    }    
}
```

And then in start up you register them as scoped, just as before in ConfigureServices. However in `Configure` you will access them as scoped.

For example

*startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<ConcreteA>();
    services.AddScoped<ConcreteB>();  

    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    // Create a new IServiceScope that can be used to resolve scoped services.
    using(var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()) {
        // resolve the services within this scope
        ConcreteA A = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConcreteA>();

        //ConcreteA instance and injected ConcreteB are used in the same scope

        //do something
        A.Run();           
    }

    //both will be properly disposed of here when they both got out of scope.
}
```

The `ConcreteA` and by extension `ConcreteB` used above will be in the same scope.

Comment: I agree... That is a more appropriate pattern.

Comment: @Nkosi   so why we needs to use `app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()`, isn't that ConcreteA and ConcreteB alread registered as "Scoped"

Comment: @secondimage They are registered with the DI container. But you need to resolve them first in order to use them. Using them on their own mean the DI container is unaware since it did not create the instances.

Comment: @secondimage Registering something as "Scoped" means that a unique one should be created _per scope_. If you don't create a scope, how does the DI container know what scope they're created against, or when they should be disposed of?

Comment: @John  So when DI resolves services normally as `public ConcreteA(ConcreteB B) {this.B = B;}`, who created the scope? DI or MVC middleware?

Comment: @secondimage in the above example the scope was created manually. Normally in MVC that scope is created by the framework for each HTTP request.

Comment: @Nkosi  if DI container is unaware since it did not create the instances, those instances will hang around( not being disposed off)? am I correct on this point? if yes, in my case, I was accessing the static method of `ConcreteA`, no instances is required, so no instance will hang around because there isn't an instance exists?

Comment: @secondimage But the static method would have caused other instance to be created that become captured from a completely separate scope. The instance created by the provider there will remain .

Comment: @Nkosi I think this is the fundamental part I'm missing. when use `serviceProvider` to create `ConcreteB`, does it mean DI contain create and provide  an instance of `ConcreteB`? and you mentioned there is a completely separate scope, so what are those two scopes, created by whom?

Comment: @secondimage You calling a static method or creating manually an object and the service provider (DI container) creating an instance are separate scopes.

Comment: @Nkosi   so you mean calling a static method is like creating a "singleton" scope, then DI contain create an instance in "scoped" scope, therefore there are two different scopes which causes captured dependencies issue?

Comment: @secondimage Yes that is the crux of it.

Comment: @Nkosi  sorry one last question, if we registered both `ConcreteA ` and `ConcreteB ` as 'transient' as `services.AddTransient<ConcreteA>;
   services.AddTransient<ConcreteB>;`, then manually create a new scope doesn't work any more in this case?